# cannot initialize SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying SDL2 for ios. I followed [this](https://github.com/bminor/SDL/blob/master/docs/README-ios.md) instructions to build libsdl2.a and libsdlmain.a.

Have used the built in ios template xcode project.

But gives me error while Initialization.

SDL Error: Application didn’t initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?

could anyone help me?

```
#include "SDL.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    int done;
    SDL_Event event;

    /* initialize SDL */
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* seed random number generator */
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* create window and renderer */
    window =
        SDL_CreateWindow(NULL, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                         SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!window) {
        printf("Could not initialize Window\n");
        return 1;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (!renderer) {
        printf("Could not create renderer\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Enter render loop, waiting for user to quit */
    done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                done = 1;
            }
        }
 
        SDL_Delay(1);
    }

    /* shutdown SDL */
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?

Comment: Yea tried.. still same error..Btw SDL_main.h is included in SDL.h right?

Comment: yes it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609570/4117728

Comment: this https://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-setting-up-sdl/ link is expired

Comment: That's why we tell people to not post link only answers. :/ You can try the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20210210042052/https://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-setting-up-sdl/ although I doubt if it is still relevant to your question. Better checkout this instead: https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/tree/master/Xcode-iOS

Comment: @brc-dd yes it is irrelevant to my issue. the website shows how to setup basic configuration which is same as my code also

Comment: @brc-dd github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2/tree/master/Xcode-iOS  this is where i have taken the code. so still that same error goes

Comment: Which template file did you use? Did you use "\_\_\_PROJECTNAME___.xcodeproj"?

Answer (score -1):

you have to Initialize SDL with SDL_Init() to Initialize everything you state: SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

Comment: He did `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`, while didn't init everything, but should already be enough in his case.